# extract part of string before and after substr

Tags: mysql

I have a DB column like this .. `part_1/part_2?part_3`

Of course I've tried `SUBSTRING_INDEX` but it does not return the central part of the string.
I want to select records that match `part_2`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using SUBSTRING_INDEX, use this : SUBSTRING(str, pos, len)

str is the column, 
pos is the position where you want to start the substring and
len is the length of the substring.

[Check out this link](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php) for more on this.

You could try something like :

```
SELECT 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(COLUMN_NAME,5), '?', 1) AS PART2 
FROM TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: length of part_1 is constant, always 4 chars. Length of part_2 and part_3 are variable. Would you still suggest SUBSTRING?

Comment: Is there a certain delimiter character between part_2 and part_3 ? Is it "?"  ?

Comment: You could try nesting a SUBSTRING_INDEX into the SUBSTRING... tell me if the edited answer works

Comment: delimiter chars are "/" and "?"

Comment: Alright so the edited answer should work with maybe a bit more work on it. SUBSTRING can also take only two arguments (the string and the starting position, it will go to the end of the string).

Comment: I thought (and tried) about nesting SUBSTRING_INDEX but I don't know how to right sintax the select